# Want get rid of "fedora/swap"

Tags: boot, fedora, grub2, lvm, swap

I had changed my swap partition, and all is works. But when reboot, Fedora 29 jammed for a long time, and enter emergency mode. It seems wait for "/dev/fedora/swap", but here only "/dev/fedora00/swap" now.

So I want delete the corresponding boot paremeter. Many methods have been used. eg, `gvim`(edit directlly), `grub2-mkconfig`, `grub-customizer`, `dracut -v /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)`.

But `rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap` always in the `/proc/cmdline`.

```
# grep fedora/swap /etc/default/grub
# grep fedora/swap /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg 
# grep fedora/swap /proc/cmdline
\\vmlinuz-4.20.12-200.fc29.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora00-root ro resume=/dev/mapper/fedora00-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora00/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora00/swap rhgb quiet LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 initrd=\initramfs-4.20.12-200.fc29.x86_64.img
```

How can I delete this paremeter.

PS, I had `refind` installed.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. Those parameters comes from `refind` whick inherit from grub2. I searched the bin files installed by refind, and found this.

```
 mkrlconf --force
```

Then refind's conf rebuilded, same as grub' conf.

I want close this topic.

Comment: no need to close- self answering is fine, and what you discovered can be useful for others too